# Can't load a Haskell dll on Windows

Tags: r, haskell, dll

I often create some DLLs with Haskell that I load in R, and this works very well.

But I have some code dealing with the `xlsx` library, I can compile it to a DLL without issue, but when I load the DLL in R, this totally crashes the R session. However this occurs on Windows only, there's no issue on Linux.

I managed to find a minimal example and there's something weird. This is my minimal example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module TestDLL where
import Codec.Xlsx
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Foreign
import Foreign.C
import Foreign.C.String (peekCString, newCString)

test :: IO ()
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  let value = toXlsx bs ^? ixSheet "List1" .
              ixCell (3,2) . cellValue . _Just
  putStrLn $ "Cell B3 contains " ++ show value

... some elementary functions here ...
```

If I compile this code to a DLL, loading this DLL in R crashes the R session on Windows. There's no such issue if I remove the `test` function. However the `test` function is not even exported (with `foreign export`) and it is not called by the other functions, isn't it weird ? If I don't export this function and if I don't use it, why the DLL deals with this function ?

And more importantly, why the R session crashes when I load the DLL, and how to fix that ?

## Edit

I have a more minimal example now. This works:

```
test :: IO Xlsx
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  return $ toXlsx bs
```

And this crashes:

```
test :: IO (Maybe Worksheet)
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  return $ toXlsx bs ^? ixSheet "List1"
```

It looks like Windows has a problem with `^?`.

## Edit 2

No crash with this equivalent code:

```
test :: IO (Maybe Worksheet)
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  let xlsx = toXlsx bs
  let sheets = _xlSheets xlsx
  let mapping = DM.fromList sheets
  return $ DM.lookup "List1" mapping
```

Windows has a problem with `^? ixSheet`. Now let me try on my real example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution (**edit: I have one, see below**) but I can say this is due to the limit of number of exported symbols.

When I compile the code

```
test :: IO (Maybe Worksheet)
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  let xlsx = toXlsx bs
  let sheets = _xlSheets xlsx
  let mapping = DM.fromList sheets
  return $ DM.lookup "List1" mapping
```

and I inspect the DLL with [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com/), I see there are 48318 exported symbols. That's acceptable.

But for the other code:

```
test :: IO (Maybe Worksheet)
test = do
  bs <- L.readFile "report.xlsx"
  return $ toXlsx bs ^? ixSheet "List1"
```

the generated DLL reaches the maximal number of exported symbols: there are 65535=2^16-1 exported symbols. This DLL is "truncated".

## Edit: A possible solution !

A possible solution consists in using a `def` file. In a file `MyDef.def`, list the functions you want to export, e.g. `funexport` and `HsStart`, like this:

```
EXPORTS
 funexport
 HsStart
```

and add `MyDef.def` at the end of the command line you use to compile:

```
ghc -shared foo.hs StartEnd.c -o foo.dll MyDef.def
```

I have just tested this solution and it works. However this is the first time I test it, so I would not guarantee yet. I'm also surprised that `ghc` does not automatically do that.

Comment: Not a Haskell user, but that seems like pretty crazy behaviour. This also looks related: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5987

Comment: Yes, that's strange. At the end, with `MyDef.def`, I have only two exported symbols and the DLL works. I'm wondering why GHC exports >65535 useless symbols.

Comment: It's not that strange if you think about it. The way function applications work in GHC means it requires an info table and a closure for each function it implements. which means, if you have a Haskell dll referencing another Haskell dll (such as when GHC and cabal use dynamic way) we need the info and closures to be available. Perhaps a flag to indicate that the dll won't be used as an import would be helpful, I'll add a note. What is a bug however is that we re-export functions imported from other packages. I'll look into fixing that for GHC 8.4.